# Django website with secondary SQLite database local

Tags: python, django, web-hosting

I have created a webframework in Django which functions like an interactive dashboard. There is however the problem that the webframework contains data that I can't put in an online environment, but has to stay in a local SQL storage. The webframework has to run on three computers that do not have access the command prompt, therefore I can't run a local Django project on each of the computers

Is the following possible?

- Host a Django website (just a shell) with user authentication and an online database that just manages the users.
- Each computer has its own local SQL storage that Django is accessing i.e. SQLlite file that is present on the desktop. In other words the SQL db that I want Django to access is not present on the hosting machine but on that of the recipient.

In this case, the worst case scenario would be that someone breaks into the webframework but can not access the files since they are only available locally.

Am I overlooking anything or is this possible? I'm aware that this is very unusual and not very pratical, but it is the only think I can think of. If there is better alternative I would be open to suggestions.

Regards

Comment: Although I don't fully understand what and why you want to achieve, you may want to look into [multiple databases](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/multi-db/)

Comment: For some reason I feel you are solving the problem with wrong architecture. Is this local data needed permanently or is only required on run time? i.e suppose if you stop django and restart it, do you want this data to still exist or repopulate it again as requests come by?

Comment: Not sure if you have considered trying **cashing** the data (which is local to the server).

Comment: To be more specific:

I host Django on an external webservice, which just contains the shell and all the code for API calls. When one of the three computers that is intended to go the webframework, I want Django to access the local SQL database that is present on the recipients computer for API calls, not a database that is hosted elsewhere.